# jquery mobile listview slow and non smooth scrolling

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile

built an app i jquery mobile, it is almost finished, and after deploying the app to phonegap we discovered that the scrolling and the total feeling is not smooth and the scroll is slow and feels weird.
i have tried almost everything,

1) `$document.bind("touchstart", function(event){})`

2) `$.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 0;`

3) using [scrollview.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/experiments/scrollview)

4) removed `ul > li` and placed `divs` instead, removed anchors `<a>`

all of the above and nothing has changed, scroll still stuck. do you have any idea?

try browsing the app in safari in your iphone to see what i'm talking about.

http://saloona.co.il/mobile

thank you

Answer (score 7):

**jquery.mobile-1.1.1**

removing the content wrapper fixed it for me.

```
<div data-role='content'> </div>
```

it scrolls just as smooth as a webpage in safari.

Comment: The answer by @theRemix works surprisingly well and it doesn't brake the application.
It also works for jQuery Mobile 1.2.0 Alpha where this is still an issue.

Comment: You removed the div that is mentioned in answer? My application broker because of this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with poor performance and scrollview, especially on android. Generally, the more complicated your DOM gets the less performant scrollview becomes. 
The JQM team [addresses this in their last major release](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/04/13/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0/):

> Alternate approaches use JavaScript-based momentum scrollers to achieve true fixed toolbars, but these only work on a small subset of platforms, have non-native scrolling physics, and can introduce performance and usability issues in less capable devices.

Therefore they switched to real fixed toolbars (`position:fixed`) in the newest release, which is pretty much supported by the most devices in use. I think this is the best way to go.